Ediitext getting under keyboard kotlin android
I have a fragment, in that i have a scrollview,(edittext inside scrollview)  and recyclerview as well. when i am clicking edittext, keyboard is hiding it.
I have only one Activity and many fragments so i cannot use android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" in manifest. (if i write in manifest it's working fine but it effects all fragments, which i don't want).
In fragment i already tried
activity?.window?.setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN
) 

but it's not working.
Someone please help me.
